# How Would Ordinary People Be Persuaded To Join An Adventurer's Party?

Tags: society, low-fantasy

Okay, so I'm trying to make a story inspired by RPGs, and a common trope in RPGs (as far as I know) is that one can recruit people into their "party" and take them on their journey. Usually, the method of recruitment is by talking to them, fulfilling sidequests, or perhaps saving them from a monster or villain.

Now, in many ways, this mechanic makes no sense. You're telling me that if you meet a girl named Miranda and bring the precious jewel her great-grandfather lost to bandits back to her, she'll join your dangerous, monster-filled journey, putting her very *life* at risk? Or that since you and that one stranger you met in a tavern found some common ground he introduced himself as Aaron and joined your team? That doesn't make much sense, now does it?

Neither does journeying with an adventurer just because they saved your life;
I know medieval peasants were tough; they'd kill wolves going after their flocks and fight Vikings with farming tools, but that *still* doesn't make one qualified to fight a dragon (typical fantasy adventure fare), and most sane peasants will (quite rightly and naturally) *avoid* monsters.

Thus, my question is **What Methods Will Best Enable Adventurers To Persuade Ordinary People They Encounter During Their Journey To Join Them?**

*Specifically,* what methods will persuade peasants (along with the odd noble, mage, or outcast), or people with careers and likely families to join a stranger on his or her dangerous journey, keeping in mind that monsters and magic can and *will* be involved? Would the promise of profit alone be enough? I seriously doubt the average person *is* that greedy/foolish/gullible, but I digress.

As always, I appreciate your input and feedback. If you feel the need to VTC or downvote, please give me an explanation so I can improve this question. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: @Tantalus' touch., thank you, I did not mean to post a POB. I just edited my question.

Comment: They want to escape crushing debt.  They've made enemies of the local lord.  They're in some other legal trouble.  They're part of a faction in secret rebellion to the local king.  They're being pressured into an arranged marriage.  They just don't like being a powerless peasant.  They recognize how glamorous and profitable adventuring can be, despite the danger.  They want to see the world outside the tiny village where they'd otherwise be stuck all their lives.  Their family is dead to bandits and their house burned down leaving them nothing keeping them here.

Comment: Still writer's choice, I meant that you should re-model the whole question not just the highlighted bit. As @causative suggests, the possibilities are endless.

Comment: @Tantalus'touch.: ah, sorry. I will do my best.

Comment: @causative: whoa, trying to point out how broad I made my question? Because if so, you succeeded....and also gave me some great ideas!

Comment: They're a traveling merchant who got robbed and needs a new start. They want to travel to meet relatives but need protection against highwaymen and can't pay for guards.  They actually strongly agree with the adventurer's major quest.  Their husband just died and they can't keep the farm by themselves.  They're a second son who won't inherit and his alternative is the army. Basically you need a reason for them to be dissatisfied with where they are, and/or a reason for them to desire the travel or glory of adventuring.  Similar to why young men join the army.

Comment: Why do you need peasants to join your party? What would be their function? Main characters are **never** ordinary people, they are always unordinary in one way or another.

Comment: @Otkin: exactly, that's the problem with this mechanic. Somehow ordinary people have abilities that can be useful to extraordinary people, not in _regular life_, but _on their journey._ For example, perhaps a blacksmith has an unusual knack for taking down tough and/or armored opponents. Or perhaps that hot Dancer brings out the inner potential of the hero. It doesn't necessarily need to make any more sense than oversized weapons do.

Comment: How low is your fantasy? Can't your party just kidnap supporting characters and induce the Stockholm syndrome once they are sufficiently far away from the original location? If your fantasy is set up in medieval setting kidnapping would be the easiest method for the majority of commoners and most likely the only way for high-prestige occupations such as blacksmith. Journeyman level craftsmen may join voluntarily since they may want the protection of your party while they gain experience.

Comment: Alice: "Hello everyone eyes over here please and raise your hand those going for the Naruto run at Area 51 tonight, I still have 6760 set of bulletproof vests grab them now while stocks last..."

Comment: Was there *ever* an adventuring quest which had trouble recruiting people to accompany the adventuring party? Many people yearn to go on an adventurous quest; many people can be motivated by gratefulness, or by duty, or, ever since the Lydians invented coins almost three thousand years ago, *money*. All those Sherpas and porters and Indian guides etc. who accompanied Edmund Hillary, and Burton and Speke, and Livingstone, and Lewis and Clark, they did it for material gain. But anyway, this question is asking about the actions of the characters in the story.

Comment: *"That doesn't make much sense, now does it?"*... umm, yes it does. Have you never met a friendly group of people at an event, or a bar, or a party, and then gone off with the for a night of crazyness and adventure? How is this different? Not everyone, or even many, will want to join on a multi-day trip. But some would!

Comment: I didn't downvote / vtc but this seems very story based.

Comment: I suggest reading Tolkien.  Hobbits live a very settled and ordinary life until they get wrangled into adventures by cunning wizards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subtle mind control** is the obvious answer.

People who are "protagonists" are simply surrounded by a near-imperceptible field of allure which drives people to be willing to throw away their established lives and join someone they just met on a likely lethal journey.

Of course, most people don't know this as the powerful heroes often end up in positions of power and suppress ideas like that, but among the nobility or in-the-know populous, its not uncommon to hide your noble scion, have the princess unexpectedly be on a "trip", or for parents to hide their progeny in the basement when people who have distinctive haircuts and talk loudly about heroic quests come to town. In fact, side-quests and quests given by townsfolk or even people in power are usually more about getting the hero away from their sons and daughters rather than actually accomplishing the goal (eg "Go fetch 50 apples, because then you won't have time to hang around in the village and convince my son to pick up the sword and go with you")

Comment: Interesting! I could definitely use this idea; perhaps instead of a field of allure, adventurers have a certain charm that calls to those wanting adventure, or even something new in their lives, while also enhancing and molding someone's desire to repay someone for saving their life or slaying the Orcs attacking their village? Hmm...

Comment: Oh, even better idea! Magically Induced Celebrity Worship! Plenty of people will do crazy things for their idols, so it'll be relatable and everything! Granted, your example sidequest will have an interesting twist: "Go fetch 50 apples, because then you won't be there when my daughter shows up with a sword looking to join you."

Comment: Everyone's answer was helpful, but your answer inspired me to give adventurers 'auras' that give people a sense of who they are, so thanks for your help, I'm much closer to finishing my world now!

Answer (score 4):

- The side quest relates to how the new recruits no longer fits in.
  A village was raided by orcs. The heroes have to recover the captured damsels in distress. The wife of one potential recruit could not be rescued alive, so he decides to leave the village and becomes a professional orc-slayer.
- Helping the side quest means that the new recruit no longer fits in.
  A village was raided by orcs. The heroes have to recover the captured damsels in distress. One villager goes along as a local guide, and slays his or her share of orcs along the way. The other villagers appreciate that the orcs were slain, but they do not appreciate a vicious killer in their midst.
- Triggering the side quest was *right*, but nobody likes a Cassandra truth.
  A village headman is trading with an orc band. One villager calls upon the adventurers to put a stop to it. They stop it, but afterwards the "snitch" is no longer quite welcome in the village and leaves with the orc-slayers.

Comment: Thanks, o.m.! I really like these mechanics, they'd fit nicely into my story!

Answer (score 2):

As seen in many stories, time is a factor, and a potential great risk later in time is often preferred to a certain small consequence now. Where the seductive call of adventure, fame and riches doesn't go, a not so subtle threat can do miracles.

You can choose: being imprisoned now for wearing an even number of shoelaces, violating this morning executive order of his majesty the king Alappapaluzzu III and 1/2 and face the dire consequences of angering his majesty, or join the party being assembled under the fund-less blessing of his majesty to risk your life if and when you manage to face the nameless menace laying at the side of mount Moon (terms and conditions apply, by signing you agree to all the points listed in the agreement available somewhere on Feb. 30th of every month)

You can see an example of this in Kubrick's Barry Lindon: first Barry joins the British army because he is penniless and chased for having killed a person in a duel, then after having deserted the British army, is captured by a Prussian officer. Faced with the choice of being returned to the British or enroll for the Prussians, he "happily" volunteers for the Prussians.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Looking back now, I can't believe I didn't remember all the times I've seen someone join a band of heroes because they were trying to avoid something _else_. The best answers really are right there in front of you, aren't they?

Answer (score 2):

> Now, in many ways, this mechanic makes no sense

I think this is the core of the problem. There isn't a "mechanic". Humans (and whatever other beings you have around) aren't automatons. They have their own dreams, desires, world-views, etc. *Some* aren't the adventuring type.

I'm personally annoyed just by routine travel - I'm not really going to be motivated to go somewhere and kill goblins or rats or whatever.

Others, however, jump at the opportunity to experience new things.

Others still aren't really for or against but can be incentivised by something - promised riches are a good motivator.

If you think the promise for wealth isn't convincing, then you don't know about financial cons - the promise for money is the prime convincing argument to go into pyramid schemes, Ponzi schemes, and any other sort of fraud. These are also quite successful in convincing people to risk their own wealth.

I'm not implying that "an adventure" is some sort of con but evidence suggests that *promises* for something are effective. It doesn't need to be money specifically, the promise of glory or excitement are also possibilities. Wouldn't even be the first time in history that people were convinced to do "an adventure" based on more or less nothing upfront but the potential payoff later:

- In 1096 Peter the Hermit managed to convince *tens of thousands* to go on foot to Jerusalem and fight the Muslim. All people that weren't even any sort of military or really special. This is known as [the Peasant's Crusade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Crusade) and it succeeded as far as they travelled from France to the Asia Minor, which is a feat by itself. For the record, this force suffered a *crushing* defeat once a real army reached it. So, the actual "crusade" part of it failed but let me emphasise *people went there*.
- Later in 1212 there was [the Children's Crusade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Crusade). The details aren't quite clear but there was *something*. The organisers are said to be a couple of boys who riled up other children to go and fight for Jerusalem. They didn't get there but did at least start.

There are other things than *just* promises that can motivate people to go on "adventure". In fact, the crusades above tapped into these other factors.

- Somebody might just not like their lot in life. Joining an adventure might be a preferable. A peasant's life is not worth much, so any alternative is usually better.
- People can use it as an opportunity to *escape*. It's a variation of the above in many ways but still useful to remember that people might already be incentivised to leave. Joining a group just helps that.
- People can join because their friends or family had joined.

There are many, many, *many* reasons one might want to go adventuring or not. It's not a binary "yes" or "no" that the adventuring party can just flip with a predefined set of actions. You can certainly *influence* how people feel about something and tip the scales but, again, humans are complex creatures. Not a complex vending machine where you enter the correct token, choose the correct combination and they just do what they are told.

Comment: Your answer reads like a frame challenge, but I still very much appreciate it; it will help me figure out recruitment methods and maybe even reopen this question.