# Implications of Adventurer's Aura

Tags: society, low-fantasy

**Implications of Adventurer's Aura**

Okay, so this questions concerns my explanation for the recruitment mechanic in RPGs. Basically, all adventurers (which may hold the title of "hero" or "villain") have an aura about them that gives someone a sense of who they are. An adventurer that is trustworthy, with a good heart, will give that impression to those around him. However, this also means a villain will have an ominous presence; people will feel that he/she means serious trouble.

This same aura elevates the bonds formed between comrades; people tend to sense and gravitate to kindred spirits, and an adventurer's aura enhances this effect, making companions and followers come to them naturally. An aura also interacts with that of others; thus the bonds forged by battle, adventures, or even familiarity ("Hey, Gustav the Blacksmith. I had a feeling you needed some help?") can become spiritual connections.

Finally, as if all that wasn't enough, an aura calls to those who seek adventure, a greater cause, or perhaps even a place to belong and/or companionship. Thus, an adventurer will not only attract followers, but gain them naturally. I believe this perfectly explains why people come out of the woodwork to support and even join the 'Chosen One' in so many stories and games, but I am a bit concerned as to what this means for society in general.

Surely people will start to recognize that people are drawn to join adventurers, heroes, and villains in lives of danger and that it is dangerous to associate with them, yes? So, how would that affect how people would deal with adventurers?

**Essentially**, I'm asking about a social aspect of my world, namely the dealing of people with adventurers. Adventurers are necessary, as they deal with monsters far better than anyone else can, *however,* due to an adventurer's aura it seems logical that sane people will keep as far away from adventurers as possible, to avoid becoming one themselves. In other words, I have to ask "how would aura influence social interaction?"

**Additional Information:**

Please assume the standard medieval fantasy here; I've been told there is no standard medieval society, but I believe most people understand what medieval fantasy entails. I'm asking about **one aspect** of society, namely how non-adventurers would handle social interaction with adventurers. Would they avoid it at all costs, or just be aloof and distant to adventurers to prevent forming a Bond? Finally, **Aura cannot be ignored, it is a subconscious effect that one can become aware of and account for.**

Comment: Is this something that people notice consciously, or subconsciously?

Comment: "what is the effect of X on society?" is always too broad...

Comment: @KeizerHarm: oh yeah, I have to put that in! It's mostly subconscious, like for how we can get a 'gut feeling' for who someone is, but one can be conscious of it as well. I assume (I could be wrong) that aura recognization will start out as subconscious then become consciously recognized as people realize it in their day-to-day lives.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica: I am trying, but this is a rather large question. I just added specifics underneath the bolded question, does it help?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered for the very same core set of reasons as [my last post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/195965/). Even though I wrote that in the answer box, it was an explanation for why that question was fundamentally flawed. I see this one the same way. There is no way to claim that "society" will do this thing or that thing. Especially when we drop a fantasy element into it. Asking "what would society do" is simply the wrong question here. There isn't a logic board controlling it. People can do whatever - it's the author's job to make the actions believable.

Comment: @VLAZ:  So, if I understand you correctly, this is a Sandbox question, yes? How would I migrate it?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct migration to the sandbox. You can simply copy/paste it from here and post it [in the sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)

Comment: @VLAZ: thanks, I will do that!

Comment: Really, really - no "standard" anything unless you describe what you mean by it, in precisely what culture  and to whom. Standard medieval fantasy in China would involve a feudal system and a burgeoning shogunate, in east Africa, tribal wars, in Arctica, probably a great seal harvest, in north America - well it depends who you ask. Be specific.